# Transposing rows to columns dynamically

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, transpose, orders

I'm using c#,
I have a DataTable in my Windows form as shown below.

```
Ref1  |  ItemNo  | ItemDesc
1     |  54637   | Cleaner
2     |  54638   | Cloth
1     |  54638   | Cloth
1     |  54639   | Spray Bottle
2     |  54637   | Cleaner
```

I need to get all of the products for each Ref1 in a separate column. So i need to get the following.

```
Ref1  |  ItemNo1 | ItemNo2 | ItemNo3 | ItemNo4
1     |  54637   | 54638   | 54639   | NULL
2     |  54638   | 54637   | NULL    | NULL
```

I could possibly have up to 50 items for some of the Refs, but only 1 or 2 for others.

What would be the most efficient way to get this done?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hello, have you tried something like this: [link](https://techbrij.com/pivot-c-array-datatable-convert-column-to-row-linq). Not that hard to search for an example on how to pivot a datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there's no really good way but this is how it should work

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Ref1", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("ItemNo", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("ItemDesc", typeof(string));

table.Rows.Add(1, 12345, "Test");
table.Rows.Add(1, 12346, "Test2");
table.Rows.Add(1, 12347, "Test3");
table.Rows.Add(2, 12345, "Test");

DataTable tableNew = new DataTable();

tableNew.Columns.Add("Ref1", typeof(int));

var result = table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("Ref1"));
var max = result.Max(x => x.Count());

for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
{
    tableNew.Columns.Add($"ItemNo{i}", typeof(int));
}

foreach (var group in result)
{
    var newRow = tableNew.NewRow();
    newRow.SetField<int>("Ref1", group.Key);

    var itemNo = 1;
    foreach(var row in group)
    {
        var val = row.Field<int>("ItemNo");
        newRow.SetField<int>($"ItemNo{itemNo}", val);
        itemNo++;
    }
    tableNew.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

I would advise to move parts of the logic to an SQL query if the data comes from a database

Comment: Thank you user1711390. This is exactly what I was looking for.